# Git as a remote backup and update system

Tags: git, embedded, backup

I have a remote device which I access over a wireless and intermittent link.
The device logs daily data, and I'd like to be able to get all updates in a robust way.
I thought of using git for the purpose:

- I'd have a periodic job which would git commit all the logs on the remote
- At the local server, I'd git pull any new log, so that the underlying protocol would handle the atomicity and robustness of the connection

However, I still have an issue: how do I keep the remote repository "small"? I'd like to purge in some way the revisions which I already got on the local server, but keep the history on the local server.

I tried with git filter branch and repack, but it breaks any clones. I believe it is the same with git rebase --interactive, with the added issue of requiring manual editing of the file (i.e. changing pick -> squash).

Maybe creating new branches every time and deleting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about using up space for the repository on the remote system, then I would suggest not using Git on the remote system at all.

Maybe consider using [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to sync between the local and remote systems. For keeping a history on the local system, you can then commit to a Git repository on the local system after each `rsync`. This way you have a backup, with complete history, on the local system and no history at all on the remote.

Comment: suppose I miss the synchronization window one day: I'd loose that snapshot. That's where git comes in: it keeps the previous' day snapshot for me to pull as soon as I can reconnect. This is not what I get with rsync, which is really network efficient as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Git is rather overkill, when you could just rotate the log files daily and rsync/scp them away, removing the files you've just copied (apart from the current log file, which might still be being written to).

Comment: Well... git is space efficient, since it stores just the diffs, and it keeps track of where the client is w/respect to the history. Moreover, I need to deal with binary files (actually rrd files) which just don't get rotated in the usual way (i.e. copy and truncate). I am of course aware of the logrotate way, and thank you for pointing it out in the discussion, it's just that I was trying to see the pros and cons of each solution.

Comment: You didn't mention RRD in your question, so I interpreted it as "regular" log files, which just get new stuff appended. Is it very meaningful to put RRD files into version control anyway? They provide their own history (usually of course with lower resolution the further back you go).

Also, git still is less space-efficient than simple daily rotated files (using `dateext` as opposed to number suffixes), especially since you can remove the files from the source device when you're done copying them over to where space isn't a problem.